# Creating a set of functions in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, function

So I'm trying to gain a better understanding of JQuery and its use for web content and web applications so just hear me out here please.  The goal of this test page is to be able to use the buttons to change, create, and delete content.  Another goal is to test out the functionality of using the "enter" key to click one of the buttons from the text box (simulating user the enter key to click a submit button).  This is the code that I developed and I'm a bit confused on how to fix the error of "destroyContent" is not defined.  Obviously my syntax is off but I'm not sure how to fix it.  Could anybody assist and possibly point me towards some useful reference material?

The JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Scan').keypress(keyHandler);
});
$.keyHandler = function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $(this).blur();
        $('#destroy').focus().click()
    }
}
$.changeHeading1 = function () {
    x = document.getElementById("Heading1")
    x.innerHTML = "It has changed";
}
$.createContent = function () {
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    var node = document.createTextNode("This is new");
    para.appendChild(node);

    var element = document.getElementById("div1");
    element.appendChild(para);
}
$.destroyContent = function () {
    var child = document.getElementById("p1");
    child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
}
```

(I promise it looks a lot better in my actual code, I just have a hard time formatting on here)

For the HTML:

```
<h1 id="Heading1" />
<p id="p1" />
<button type="text" id="Scan" />
<button type="button" onclick="changeHeading1()" />
<button type="button" onclick="createContent()" />
<button type="button" id="destroy" onclick="destroyContent()" />
```

Comment: It does looks a lot better :)

Comment: Why are you creating these functions as methods of `$` when they make no use of jQuery at all?

Comment: Well there in lies part of my confusion I suppose.  I was just trying out a few things that I saw while searching around for how to create/define functions in JQuery and that was one thing I found.  But apparently it doesn't apply to my situation.

Comment: There's a difference between JavaScript and jQuery. jQuery is just a library for accessing and manipulating the DOM, it's not a complete replacement of everything JavaScript has.

Comment: Right.  I guess I'm just having trouble trying to mix the two of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing that might help is `$` is just a variable on the global namespace - which in this case is `window`. If you go to chrome console you'll see this by typing `window.$`.  There is nothing special about it.  There is also `window.jQuery` which is the same as `window.$`.

So when you access a function it will try and get the variable in the current scope. So when you do:

```
<button type="button" id="destroy" onclick="destroyContent()" />
```

It's the same as doing `window.destroyContent()`. If you want to access your version which is a property on the $ variable. So you can change it either of these:

```
onclick="$.destroyContent()"
onclick="window.$.destroyContent()"
```

But since you want to better understand jQuery I would avoid adding handlers (as most people will suggest) to the markup. Instead create handlers via jQuery for example:

```
$('#destroy').click(function() {
  var child = document.getElementById("p1");
  child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
});
```

Reading up on the jQuery events API will help better understand how to do this. They have great examples :)

Comment: I had actually considered going the route that you suggested at the bottom there and I know I could have gotten that correct, but then I couldn't think of a way to also make it so that pressing the enter key from the text box would also fire the click event

Comment: Or just `$('#destroy').click(function(){ $('#p1').remove(); });`

Comment: It doesn't make any difference if you have a click handler bound by `.click()` or with the `onclick` attribute, in regards of triggering the event from outside.

Comment: You also don't need to do focus().click() just $('#destroy').click(). It will trigger the event handles automatically.

Comment: One other note as you can see this could get messy if you have lots of behaviour and you're triggering events in many different handlers. I've done it - it can get very messy. If needed (by larger apps) it's a good idea to separate this behaviour. See backbone, ember, angular, etc for good approaches.

Comment: One final bit: I'm still trying to use the keypress handler to detect the use of the enter key in the textbox and I still have the keypress event handler being attached to the textbox in the `(document).ready(function)` and I still have `function keyHandler(e){..}` set up after that.  Would that be correct? (refer to the code in my original post)

Comment: @Jared In your original example you would need to use $.keyHandler I believe. I've put together a fiddle using your code which has the enter key working as you want (I think): http://jsfiddle.net/ZCNBW/2/

Answer (score 2):

You're creating `destroyContent` as a member of `$` but not calling it that way:

`$.destroyContent = function () {` versus `onclick="destroyContent()"`

You should either define `destroyContent` outside of `$` or call it with the `$`. One of these:

```
function destroyContent() {
    var child = document.getElementById("p1");
    child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
}
```

or

`<button type="button" id="destroy" onclick="$.destroyContent()">`

Comment: Although I guess I didn't quite understand, if I created it just as 'function destroyContent(){...}' then I should call it as 'onclick="destroyContent"'?

Comment: If you create it that way, call it as `onclick="destroyContent()"` with parentheses. Or better yet, if you want to use jQuery, attach it to the button in code: `$(function() { $('#destroy').click(destroyContent); });`

Comment: Well that'as exactly what I have `function destroyContent() {..}` and `onclick="destroyContent()"` and I still get the same error: destroyContent is not defined.  I'm wondering if it could have anything to do with the fact that my script has both javascript and jquery elements in it?

Comment: Do you have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or something where you can reproduce the error?

Comment: Alright, I know that error came about because I had 'src="jquery-1.9.1.js"' in my script tag, but how can I have both javascript and jquery elements in it if I don't include the jquery library?  Or I'm guessing I'll have to split them into seperate files...

Comment: You can have multiple `script` tags. Put `<script src="jquery..."></script>` first and then `<script>//your javascript code</script>` after it.

Comment: Ahhh.  I can't tell you how many "duh" moments I have because I'm not starting with simple solutions, I jump immediately to more complicated ones.  Thank you!